# Using instanceof when one class don't know about the other

Tags: java, class

I'm currently working with two different classes, one called `Human` and one called `Fysiker`. Human got two different class attributes, *age* and *name* whereas Fysiker got three: *age*, *name* and *startyear*. My code is inheriting attributes from the Human class to the Fysiker class.

**The goal** is to make sure that if I have two objects of the Fysiker class with the same *age*, then I want to sort them after their *startyear*.

**The problem** is that I want to sort my code, using `Collections.sort`, which I've implemented. The problem is a bit tricky, but I have created an `ArrayList` which takes the argument `Human`. It has to, because at some point I want to fill that list with both `Human` and `Fysiker`.

Then I've implemented a `CompareTo`, one for `Fysiker` and one for `Human`. When I fill my list with only objects of class `Fysiker`, it still won't sort them after *startyear*, but only after *age*. This basically makes me think that since the `ArrayList` simply takes `Human`, it' using my `CompareTo` for the `Human` class instead of the `Fysiker` class. I've gotten the clue (from the assignment) to use `instanceOf`, but I don't know how to use this, since my `Human` class doesn't know anything about `Fysiker`, only the other way around.

I've posted another question, close to this one, but I think I've come to an understanding of what the problem is at this stage, at least closer. My code is looking like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Human implements Comparable<Human>{
        public static final List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Rutger","Oscar","Aram","Noak","Hilda","Dahl");
        public Random rand=new Random();
        public String name;
        public int age;

    public Human(int age, String name){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;

    }
    public Human(){
        this.age=rand.nextInt(101);
        this.name=names.get(rand.nextInt(names.size()));
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "åldern är:"+this.age+" "+"namnet är:"+this.name;
    }
    public int compareTo(Human o){
        return this.age-o.age;
}

}
```

And the `Fysiker` class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Fysiker extends Human{

    public int startyear;
    public Fysiker(int age, String name, int startyear){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
        this.startyear=startyear;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return startyear;
    }


    public int compareTo(Fysiker o){
        int b;
        b=(this.age>o.age ? 1:this.age<o.age ? -1:0);
        if (b==0){
            b=(this.startyear>o.startyear ? 1:this.startyear<o.startyear ? -1:0);
            return b;}
            else{
            return b;}

    }

    public String toString(){
        return "åldern är:"+this.age+" "+"namnet är:"+this.name+" "+"började fysik:"+String.format("F%02d",this.startyear%100);
    }

    public Fysiker(){
        this.age=15+rand.nextInt(86);
        this.name=names.get(rand.nextInt(names.size()));
        this.startyear=2015-rand.nextInt(this.age-14);
        while (this.startyear<1932){
            this.startyear=2015-rand.nextInt(this.age-14);
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Human> fysiker=new ArrayList<Human>();
        int q;



        for (q=0;q<=80;q++){
            fysiker.add(new Fysiker());
        }
        int s;
        Collections.sort(fysiker);
        for (s=0;s<=fysiker.size()-1;s++){
            //fysiker.get(0).compareTo(fysiker.get(s));
            System.out.println(fysiker.get(s).toString());
            //System.out.println(fysiker.get(0));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This has already been answered in your other question. Read your answers.

Comment: I don't see how it's been answered, sure, I know how to implement the compareTo method, but it doesn't solve the issue of having two different classes whereas one dont know about the other.

Comment: One **does** know about the other: `class Fysiker extends Human`.

Comment: Yes, Fysiker knows about Human, but not the other way around, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: And this problem has been answered. Both answers tell you that having a method compareTo(Fysiker) in the subclass doesn't make sense. Yet you're still doing it.

Comment: I suppose my poor knowledge about Java limits me here, but let's say that I do remove the compareTo in the Fysiker-class, how can I change the compareTo in the Human class so it understand that there exists such a thing as Fysiker?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The compareTo(Human) method in Fysiker should care about that. Not the one in Human.

Comment: I thought you said that it doesn't make any sense so have a compareTo method in the subclass, therefore I thought you wanted me to remove it, if that's not the case, then I'm back at square one, how can I make Human understand that there exists Fysiker?

Comment: No, that's not what I said, and that's not what the answers say. Having a method compareTo(Fysiker) in the subclass doesn't make sense, because you need to override the method of Comparable<Human>, which is compareTo(Human), not compareTo(Fysiker). The two answers also tell you that. And they have code. Read them carefully.